# Is it okay to mix apt distro channels? (i.e. xenial, artful, bionic, cosmic etc.)

Tags: apt

Everytime I `do-release-upgrade` it disables my PPA's I need, so I need to re-enable them by checking the box in Software & Updates. A few releases later, I now have a jumble of various channels for these re-enabled PPAs (`artful`, `bionic`, `cosmic`, and even debian ones like `jessie` etc in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`)

I get no errors or warnings about this. But it feels wrong deep down in my soul. Counsel?

EDIT: I can confirm having a mix does cause odd bugs, it's best to keep them all the same

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources; they are not supported by Canonical/Ubuntu, but instead supported by third party so all checks on whether your trust the 3rd party source, if it's supported in your release are on you.  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories)  As they are not supported, they of course are not tested by Canonical/Ubuntu which is why they are disabled.  Many are not needed on upgrade anyway (eg. as PPAs aren't reviewed/vetted so it's easier to put software in a PPA that will be supported in the next release) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are re-enabling the PPA's, it's a good idea to visit launchpad and see if there are version of the PPA available for the release that you are using.

Using older (newer) PPAs may work, and the system is not going to stop you, but *sometimes* worse things than "The program won't run" happen.

Please see the [pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) page.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I wish the GUI for PPA's would show colors based on status (older channel, or unable to connect). I'm tempted to code it myself. PPA's need a little love in Ubuntu land, they are tedious to manage and easy to get wrong, especially with new releases. I shouldn't have to search a website to find them, and it should automatically move them up a channel if it can when doing a release upgrade, and key management should never be manual

Comment: @Jonathan Well, it is linux!  I'm attemping to do an Arch install, and a key note from the Arch documentation says "...check the front page Arch news every time before you update..." and they are doing a rolling update process - no point releases.